# Trying to make ajax calls on my site. Works on modern browsers (IE9, Chrome, FF) but IE8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a site with ajax calls for the content, mostly because the site has a radio station and i would like the users of my site don't stop hearing the radio because they're reading other articles or something like that.

I'm using Jquery.

so... i have this function:

```
$(function(){    

            // Get a reference to the content div (into which we will load content).
            var jContent = $( "#content" );

            // Hook up link click events to load content.
            $( ".enlaceajax" ).live("click", function( objEvent ){
                    var jLink =  $(this) ;

                    // Clear status list.
                    $( "#ajax-status" ).empty();

                    //Obtenemos de donde estan obteniendo el valor del enlace. ya sea que den clic en el combo box o en un enlace normal.

                    var value = jLink.attr("value");
                    var href = jLink.attr("href");
                    alert(href);
                    if(typeof value === 'undefined')
                    {
                    var linkgo = href;  
                    }
                    else {
                    var linkgo = value; 
                    }

                    // Launch AJAX request.
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            // The link we are accessing.
                            url: linkgo,
                            // The type of request.
                            type: "GET",
                            // The type of data that is getting returned.
                            dataType: "html",

                            success: function( strData ){
                                // Load the content in to the page.


                                jContent.html( strData );
                                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
                            }
                        }                           
                        );

                    // Prevent default click.
                    return( false );                    
                }
                );

        }
        );
```

I add the code on my site via an external file. the file loads correctly and the jQuery too. I test on Firefox with firebug and everything is ok, the script works and everything is loaded on the div "content".

But, for some reason, when i try this code on IE8, it doesn't work with PHP files. When i click on a PHP file (something like `nota.php?nota=12345`) the div content just disappears. But if i click on an html link (like `test.html`) it works fine.

I've tried looking on several places and I just don't find any solution to this... also, I'm a real noob on jquery...

Comment: http://cntamaulipas.info/cntest/ there it is :(. if you click on any of the links colored with red, it should activate the function.

Comment: first, i noticed that your id of each option are the same which is not valid. ids should be unique in all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need more details on the error other than "just disapears".  Try loading IE Developer Toolbar.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: I've uploaded a test design on the FTP... its avaible at http://cntamaulipas.info/cntest/ . There you can see how actually the script get the url and get the information (i put some alerts on my code so you could see, the link the system is getting and how the system actually gets the content of the link) but when its going to display it, the <div> just dissapears...